# Почему не находит приложение при открытии intent'ом?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Такая ситуация. Я уже со всем разобрался, только вот осталось последнее))

У меня на телефоне 2 приложения, одно мое которое отправляет интент и второе `3d model viewer` то куда я хочу этот интент послать

вот так я ищу приложения которые могут открыть мой файл

```
public void reeee(View view) {
    String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic/files/default/AvatarModelDir/20160614_233755.dae";
    File file = new File(path);

    //checking if the File exists
    if(file.exists()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/xml");

        boolean result = isIntentAvailable(getApplicationContext(), intent);

        if (result){
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " + list.get(i));
    }

    return !list.isEmpty();
}
```

В списке `list`-е приложений который могут открыть мой файл, только 1 приложение

вот, что печатает лог

```
ResolveInfo{e7de143 com.android.htmlviewer/.HTMLViewerActivity m=0x608000}
```

Находит стандартный вьевер и все. Почему не находит нужно мне приложение `3d model viewer`?

Я думал, что проблема в том, что в `3d model viewer` в манифесте не прописан `intent-filter`, но на другом устройстве у меня есть файл менеджер. Я загрузил мой файл на это устройство, (на нем тоже установлено приложение `3d model viewer`) и через проводник его открываю и у меня открывается нужная мне апплекация...

Значит ее можно открыть с помощью стороннего приложения!

Что тогда с моим `intent` не так?

Проверил через приложение `Dexplorer` файл манифест и там есть нужный интент фильтр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но все равно как его вызвать?

Конечный вариант метода который работает

```
public void reeee(View view) {

    String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/default/AvatarModelDir/Anna.dae";
    File file = new File(path);

    //checking if the File exists
    if(file.exists()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/octet-stream");

        boolean result = isIntentAvailable(getApplicationContext(), intent);

        if (result){
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Подозреваю что установка типа контента в `"text/xml"` лишняя. А что бы узнать точно что за интент фильтры есть в стороннем приложении можно поставить приложение [Dexplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dexplorer) и глянуть AndroidManifest.xml нужного приложения.

Посмотрел я манифест этого HD Model Viewer, он принимает либо интенты без MIME типа, либо с MIME `"*/*"`, либо `"application/octet-stream"`. Ну и схемы поддерживает только http, https, file и content. Для вашего пути `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic/files/default/AvatarModelDir/20160614_233755.dae` система теоретически сама должна дописать схему file, но лучше задать её самому: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic/files/default/AvatarModelDir/20160614_233755.dae`. Кроме того этот путь явно внутри вашего приложения и соответственно доступ к нему будет только у вашего приложения. Так что если хотите дать к нему доступ другим приложениям через интент почитайте об этом [гайдах гугла](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html).

Comment: О какое классное приложение вы мне посоветовали! Спасибо!  Добавил описание вопроса

Comment: Так а без описания MIME типа пробовали? В общем сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: Вроде заработало, добавил рабочий вариант в вопрос)) Только странно, что когда я добавляю в `String path` схему `file` как у вас, то не проходит проверку `exists()`, а если без этого то открывает как нужно. И вот насчет доступа... Тоже странно, но согласно документации нужно в манифксте прописывать доступ и т.д. у меня этого нет и файл открывается. Не знаю, нужно ли копать и разбираться почему это работает не так как ожидается(всмысле без доступов и прочее) или если работает оставить как есть?

Comment: И вот, что хотел спросить очень важно для меня. Скажите как вы поняли, что в `setDataAndType()` нужно поставить именно `application/octet-stream` ?

Comment: Я же написал, это в манифесте написано. А по поводу того что работает без предоставления доступа странно. Но вообще можно не предоставлять доступ а просто сохранять файлы в публично доступных папках, а не у себя.

Answer (score 2):

Интренеты говорят, что ваш файл имеет MIME тип `model/vnd.collada+xml`. Попробуйте его задать в интент вместо `text/xml`.
Файловый менеджер скорее всего умеет по расширению найти верный MIME тип, поэтому и файлы открывает как надо.

Comment: То есть если я правильно понял, то именно по этому параметру менеджер и будет отыскивать приложения которые могут открыть указанный формат? Я сделал так как вы предложили, но ничего не получилось, не показывает ни одного приложения которое могло бы открывать данный параметр... Мне кажется что нужно проверить правильно ли он написан, сейчас попробую поискать

Comment: @xkor обновил свой ответ, полностью с ним согласен.